# Best Practice: check if a function exists before calling it

Tags: javascript

Say I have a method that takes an optional param that is a callback function. At some point in the method, if that function exists, I should call it. Is there a best practice for doing this?

I like this approach:
`!!callback && callback();`

But I've seen it's simplier form 
`callback && callback();`
which feels wrong (because it's not explicitly converting `callback` to a boolean).

I could of course use `typeof` and/or `if`, but those seem unnecessarily verbose.

I've googled around a bit, but I'm not seeing anything concrete on this subject. Does a best practice for this scenario exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to avoid this issue is to not have optional parameters, or at least have default values for them.

For example:

```
const emptyFn = () => {} 

function doStuff(callback = emptyFn){
    callback()
}
```

But other than that, callback && callback() is pretty well known way of doing this sort of thing, so it's not too bad imo.

Comment: `function  doStuff(callback = () => {})` also works and avoids having another symbol in the namespace. If one had multiple functions all having a parameter defaulting to the empty function, I would go with your solution, however.